# ignore empty entries - import with fast-csv to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I use fast-csv to import a CSV file in a mongodb.

How can I ignore empty entries in my csv file - that they dont import in my db:

```
{ firstname: 'foo',lastname: 'bar',driving: '', overnight: '' }
```

and my second question is: if I have a value how can I parse "true" to a Boolean instead a String ?

[image]

Comment: why not just filtering the array before importing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var filtered = {};

    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
        if (data[key] === "true" || data[key] === "false") {
            data[key] = (data[key] === "true");                 // convert to boolean
        } 
        if (data[key] !== "") {
            filtered[key] = data[key];                          // remove empty entries
        } 
    });

    dataResult.push(filtered);                                  // push to array
```